# Can't get response with PremiumVoucher api

Tags: php, api

I want to redeem Vouchers with [PremiumVoucher's](https://www.premiumvouchers.com/) API and I'm using samples code
I got this response every time :

```
{"Code":null,"SecKey":null,"IssueDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","RedeemDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","Status":"0","Amount":0.0,"Error":"Your IP Address is invalid","TransactionID":null,"InvoiceID":null}
```

This is my code :

```
<?php
function RedeemVouchers($ApiKey, $SecKey, $VoucherCode, $WorthValue, $InvoiceID)
{
$curl = curl_init();

//Create Security Hash (SHA512) Based on Params and SecKey
$SecurityHash = hash_hmac('sha512', $ApiKey . ":" . $SecKey . ":"
. $VoucherCode . ":" . $InvoiceID . ":" . $WorthValue, $SecKey);

$baseUrl = "https://www.premiumvouchers.com/api/vouchers/ReturnVouchers?";
$params = "ApiKey=" . $ApiKey . "&VoucherCode=" . $VoucherCode .
"&WorthValue=" . $WorthValue . "&InvoiceID=" . $InvoiceID .
"&SecurityHash=" . $SecurityHash;

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => $baseUrl . $params,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "",
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
"cache-control: no-cache"
)
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
echo $response;
}
}

//Call Examples

//Your APIkey and SecurityKey
$ApiKey = "***Enter APIKey";
$SecKey = "*** Enter SecurityKey ***";

///Params
$WorthValue = "USD";

//Your Website Invoice ID
$InvoiceID = "1";

//Voucher Code
$VoucherCode = $_GET['code'];

RedeemVouchers($ApiKey, $SecKey, $VoucherCode, $WorthValue, $InvoiceID);
?>
```

Can anyone help me to use this api?

Comment: Have you actually read the error message? Seems like you would need to register your IP address with the API provider. The API docs require registration so I can't go and read what they say about it